# Help with proving: P, ¬(Q ∧ P) ⊢ ¬Q

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, propositional-logic

Here's the issue, there's no usage of derived rules allowed. So no DeMorgan's Law. All that's allowed is the basic TFL elimination/introduction rules, IP, (e)X(plosion), and ⊥. I'm absolutely lost on how to get -Q, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: proof by negation, assuming Q first, then Q ∧ P per TFL ∧-intro rule based on all premises, then explode...

Comment: @DoubleKnot Aye Thank you, this one was holding me up really bad

Comment: This proof technique is a common "holding up"... There's some old saying *To speak of the false is to reveal the true...*, but it's hard to do so for some especially beginners...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, there is no need to explode.  Rather use negation introduction.

Comment: @GrahamKemp thx for your feedback in the language of logicians which is meant for a formal answer. My above colloquial language was meant as an informal hint...

Answer (score 1):

> All that's allowed is the basic TFL elimination/introduction rules, IP, (e)X(plosion), and ⊥. I'm absolutely lost on how to get -Q,

To introduce a negation, we use the rule of *negation introduction*.

Assume `Q`, somehow derive a contradiction, and discharge that assumption with the rule.

```
1|  P
2|_ ¬(Q ∧ P)
3|  |_ Q         H
 |  |  :   
m|  |  ⊥        ¬E ?,?
n|  ¬Q          ¬I 3-m
```